Issue with Google Gemini API to access Real-Time Sensor Data from Firebase and return that in chatbot responses
I'm building a predictive maintenance web app which has two sections dashboard and chatbot made with Streamlit that integrates with a Google Gemini chatbot API. I also have real-time sensor which is being generated from python script every 30 seconds and data is stored in Firebase's Realtime Database. My goal is to make the chatbot capable of accessing Firebase data dynamically so it can answer questions like "What is the current temperature?" or "What was the average temperature over the last day?" However, I’m facing issues with getting the chatbot to respond with this real-time data.
The setup includes:
Google Gemini API: Used to generate responses for the chatbot.
Streamlit App: This app has a dashboard page to display sensor data and a chatbot page.
Firebase: Stores real-time sensor data (e.g., temperature, humidity).
import streamlit as st
import google.generativeai as genai
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

load_dotenv()

genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv("GEMINI_API_KEY"))

if not firebase_admin._apps:
    cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/firebase-adminsdk.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'databaseURL': 'https://<database-name>.firebaseio.com/'
    })

sensor_data_ref = db.reference('sensorData')

def get_sensor_data():
    sensor_data = sensor_data_ref.get()
    if sensor_data:
        data_list = [
            {**values, 'id': key} for key, values in sensor_data.items() if isinstance(values, dict)
        ]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
        df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
        return df
    return pd.DataFrame()

def is_project_related(prompt):
    project_keywords = [
        "temperature", "pressure", "humidity", "current", "average", "today",
        "sensor", "dashboard", "maintenance", "real-time"
    ]
    return any(keyword in prompt.lower() for keyword in project_keywords)

def generate_response(prompt):
    if not is_project_related(prompt):
        return "I'm sorry, but I can only answer questions related to the Predictive Maintenance System project."
    
    df = get_sensor_data()
    
    if df.empty:
        return "I'm unable to retrieve data from the sensors right now. Please check if the data is being pushed correctly to Firebase."

    if "current temperature" in prompt.lower() and not df.empty:
        latest_temp = df.sort_values(by='timestamp', ascending=False).iloc[0]['temperature']
        return f"The current temperature is {latest_temp}°C."
    
    elif "average temperature" in prompt.lower() and not df.empty:
        last_day = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
        recent_data = df[df['timestamp'] > last_day]
        if not recent_data.empty:
            avg_temp = recent_data['temperature'].mean()
            return f"The average temperature over the last 24 hours is {avg_temp:.2f}°C."
        else:
            return "No data available for the last 24 hours."
    
    context = """
    You are an AI assistant for a Predictive Maintenance System project. The system uses sensors 
    (temperature, pressure, humidity, and current) connected to an ESP32 microcontroller to monitor 
    industrial equipment. It collects real-time data, uses machine learning for failure prediction, 
    and provides a dashboard for monitoring. Only respond to queries related to this system.
    """
    full_prompt = f"{context}\n\nUser: {prompt}\nAssistant:"
    model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
    response = model.generate_content(full_prompt)
    return response.text

def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title="Predictive Maintenance System", layout="wide")

    st.markdown("""
        <style>
            .navbar { display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly; font-size: 1.2em; }
            .navbar-item { cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: #007ACC; text-decoration: none; }
            .navbar-item:hover { background-color: #f1f1f1; border-radius: 5px; }
            .navbar-container { display: flex; justify-content: center; padding: 1em 0; background-color: #F0F2F6; }
        </style>
    """, unsafe_allow_html=True)

    navbar_items = st.columns(2)
    with navbar_items[0]:
        if st.button("Dashboard"):
            st.session_state.page = "Dashboard"
    with navbar_items[1]:
        if st.button("Chatbot"):
            st.session_state.page = "Chatbot"

    if "page" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.page = "Dashboard"

    if st.session_state.page == "Dashboard":
        st.header("Real-Time Sensor Dashboard")
        df = get_sensor_data()
        
        if not df.empty:
            st.write("### Latest Sensor Readings")
            latest_data = df.sort_values(by='timestamp', ascending=False).iloc[0]
            st.write(latest_data)

            st.write("### Sensor Data Over Time")
            st.line_chart(df.set_index("timestamp")[["temperature", "pressure", "humidity", "current"]])

        else:
            st.write("No sensor data available.")

    elif st.session_state.page == "Chatbot":
        st.header("Maintenance Assistant Chatbot")
        
        if "messages" not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.messages = []

        for message in st.session_state.messages:
            with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
                st.markdown(message["content"])

        if prompt := st.chat_input("Ask about the Predictive Maintenance System"):
            st.chat_message("user").markdown(prompt)
            st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})

            response = generate_response(prompt)
            with st.chat_message("assistant"):
                st.markdown(response)
            st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Below is the screenshot of app:

Firebase Data Retrieval: The get_sensor_data function retrieves real-time data from Firebase successfully on the dashboard page, but the chatbot cannot directly access the data. It defaults to using Gemini responses or returning a message that data is not available.
Chatbot Response Logic: For questions like "What is the current temperature?", the chatbot doesn’t use the Firebase data as expected. We wanted it to retrieve last added data from the python script(in final demonstration we will use real iot setup) and it as current value of that specific system. We’ve tried multiple conditions in generate_response to check if keywords like "current temperature" or "average temperature" are in the prompt, but it’s still not working as intended.
